# How can I assign an array to another variable in php?

Tags: php, arrays, variable-assignment

I have defined an array in php

```
    $letters = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","V","X","Y","Z");
```

Then I try to assign the array to a new variable, that is also an array:

```
   $new_array = array();
   $new_array =  $letters;
```

But it's not working, why?

Comment: That should work assuming they are within the same scope.. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: What do you mean by *not working* ?

Comment: So, what _does_ `$new_array` contain if not the letters array? Please be more specific.

Comment: It was empty,I omitted the $new_array = array(); and it's fine now

Comment: clearly OP has never come across range('A','Z')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just do

```
$new_array = $letters;
```

You don't have to specify the type because it is implied.

Comment: Now, I'm seriously confused.. Isn't that what he has? Why would declaring the type of `$new_array` change anything? Someone, please explain. [It works here](http://ideone.com/YlP86)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create an empty array. Your second assignment is actually correct. The nice trick is to dump content of a variable using var_dump() to see its actual value.

Try this:

```
$letters = array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","V","X","Y","Z");
$new_array = $letters;
var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Josh mentioned scope, and that may be the issue here. If `$letters` is a global and the assignment to `$new_array` is happening in a function, then `$letters` has to be declared global in the function before use.

Answer (score 0):

Use clone keyword

```
var2 = clone var1;
```

Sharing is caring. Help others with you knowledge :)